# Hand cursor is missing for "full site" link in mobile web footer

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, mobile-web, footer

The hand cursor is missing for the **full site** link in the footer of mobile-web view. For other links the hand cursor is showing properly.

Recorded the same as gif:

> [image: Full site link is not hyperlink]

While inspect the element I see the `<a href` is applied for the remaining links. For **full site** link `onclick` event is applied.

```
<a href="/contact">contact us</a>
<a onclick=" StackExchange.switchMobile("off") ">full site</a>
```

Comment: +1 although tbh, I don't think it matters in mobile view, because on an actual mobile device, the hand doesn't exist - you just tap the button